# Get DTS Step Description from TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, dts

I am trying to get the DTS Step Name/Description of a given DTS Package in **SQL2000**. I am not able to see anything in the msdb database. I can see the initial DTS name, however I dont see anything to get the details. Anybody knows where this info is stored?

Comment: I have a hazy memory that it is in MSDB somewhere. I don't have a SQL2000 instance to hand though. Maybe run SQL Profiler then in Enterprise Manager bring up the DTS package and see how Enterprise Manager gets this information?

Comment: I did. The only thing I can see is a request to the sp_get_dtspackage. I think the info might be saved in the package-data itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the contents of a DTS package directly through SQL server (they are stored as binary in `msdb.dbo.sysdtspackages` when stored in SQL server, or as binary files in the file system).

However, you can access them via the relevant OLE object - [dts.package2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa176243%28SQL.80%29.aspx).

There are several examples of using the OLE interface to extract DTS step information - [this](http://www.nigelrivett.net/DTS/ScriptDTSProperties.html) is one of them, which uses another DTS package to run VBScript to extract package information into a file. You could modify this to write data into a table in the database.